# dompdf, Store the Contents of a Wordpress Page in a Variable

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

using WordPress 3.8, i included dompdf library to generate portfolio of my site, i tried in different ways but got no solution. here is my code i tried.

```
<?php
require_once ('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$id="80";
$post = get_page($id);
$contents = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'; 
  $html.= $contents;
  $html .='</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("Dotcom Portfolio.pdf");
}
?>
```

Not: when i echo $contents variable , it prints the data which is stored in it.like

```
$post = get_page($id);
$contents = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 

echo $contents;

die();
```

but not storing in $html variable convert in PDF.

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show me what data `$content` variable holds?

Comment: it contain whole data which the dynamic WordPress page contain means all contents of a page

Comment: yes but i need to see what its html looks like. so please die `$contents` and copy paste it's value here.

Comment: it too long result can not be here in comment, when i print $content it contains pictures and graphs ans text data.

Comment: What is sent to the browser when you attempt to create the PDF? What do you get if you echo out the `$html` variable?

Comment: @BrianS yes i want to generate PDF,when i echo it shows simple text, but my HTML page contains images, and graphs too.

Comment: So if you echo out the HTML instead of render to PDF is looks ok? Could be the way you reference your images and stylesheets. Try referencing those files with a URL that includes the domain (e.g. `http://example.com/styles.css`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this steps

```
    ob_start();
    include('./some_dynamic_page.php');
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($content);
    $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("result.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

And the config:
(dompdf_config.custom.inc)

```
    //define("DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR", "/tmp");
    //define("DOMPDF_CHROOT", DOMPDF_DIR);
    define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
    //define("DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND", "PDFLib");
    define("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE", "print");
    define("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_PAPER_SIZE", "A4");
    //define("DOMPDF_DEFAULT_FONT", "serif");
    define("DOMPDF_DPI", 300);
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);
    //define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT", false);
    //define("DEBUGPNG", true);
    //define("DEBUGKEEPTEMP", true);
    //define("DEBUGCSS", true);
    //define("DEBUG_LAYOUT", true);
    //define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_LINES", false);
    //define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_BLOCKS", false);
    //define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_INLINE", false);
    //define("DOMPDF_FONT_HEIGHT_RATIO", 1.0);
    //define("DEBUG_LAYOUT_PADDINGBOX", false);
    //define("DOMPDF_LOG_OUTPUT_FILE", DOMPDF_FONT_DIR."log.htm");
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER", true);
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING", true);

    // DOMPDF authentication
    define("DOMPDF_ADMIN_USERNAME", "admin");
    define("DOMPDF_ADMIN_PASSWORD", "anypassword");
```

Comment: some_dynamic_page.php would be: <?php $id="80";
$post = get_page($id);
$contents = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
?>
<html><body><p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite templating system.</p> 
<?php echo $contents; ?>
 </body></html>

Comment: Or you can include full code directly without using "include"